# Are GET variables secure for transmitting secrets?

Tags: security, get

**Background**

I'm working on an application for my own needs, with some very lightweight frameworks. I don't want to spend time on user previlegies, logins and so on. No one but me will use it.

**My question**

Let's say I want be able to add or delete anything in my database when visiting this address:

http://www.example.com/?secret=eccbc87e4b5ce2fe28308fd9f2a7baf3

No login, just this address. How secure is that? If it's not secure, what would be a good simple solution?

**My thoughts**

- No one can guess that secret key.
- Can robots find out about it if there is no link to it?

Comment: Not that this question really seem to have anything to do with MD5, but generally you shouldn't use it, it was broken and can be guessed in practical time nowadays. Use something else like SHA1.

Comment: Where does MD5 come into your scheme? | @Cray SHA-1 is almost as broken as MD5.

Comment: How about just adding a `.htaccess` file to the directory?

Comment: Seems true, use SHA-512 instead.

Comment: The weakness here is not that a weak cryptographic hash function is used. The actual weakness is that the secret transmission is insecure as (a) it may be sniffed by attackers, and (b) it may automatically be logged by intermediate proxies and/or the target web server.

Comment: @CodesInChaos MD5 is not as broken as people like to make it out to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If its not going over SSL then it can be sniffed too. If you update on public wifi anyone can see the value. Though its quite unlikely anyone will be sniffing for your website

Answer (score 2):

If this it just for yourself, it should be ok. One caveat not mentioned yet - make sure you do not embed other sites' content into your pages, or they will see you magic value in their Referer headers.

Answer (score 1):

Your thoughts are right. So don't bookmark the URL on a public computer ;-)

If its a MD5 or another big text string is up to you...

Answer (score 0):

To answer the the question in the post title "Are GET variables secure for transmitting secrets?", the answer is no (depending on what you mean by 'secure'). As some have pointed out, although the unique URI may not be guessed it could be possible for someone to find the unique URI if they were suitably positioned on the network (coffe shop, room mate, library, university, ISP, etc).

Even if SSL (HTTPS) is used there are some weaknesses in SSL which could still reveal your traffic to a suitably positioned attacker. See SSLStrip [0], BEAST attack [1] and most recently CRIME [2] as well as others.

The real dilema is how much risk are you willing to take. If you are using the URI to view images of kittens, then you may want to accept the risk. If, however, you're using it to store your credit card details, then you may not want to accept that risk.

There are other ways in which your unique 'secret' URI may be revealed apart from packet sniffing. Another way in which it may be revealed is if from that 'secret' page you link to a third-party site and click on that link, the URI may be sent in the HTTP 'referer' header.

[0] http://www.thoughtcrime.org/software/sslstrip/

[1] http://luxsci.com/blog/is-ssltls-really-broken-by-the-beast-attack-what-is-the-real-story-what-should-i-do.html

[2] http://arstechnica.com/security/2012/09/many-ways-to-break-ssl-with-crime-attacks-experts-warn/

Answer (score -2):

Robots will find it if you put it in any kind public in the internet. After knowing the URL and writing a small bot specified for your site it's possible that someone just iter all md5s with a rainbow table. If it's just for a small management it would be ok, but it's dangerous put there some other values to check in it. Maybe the md5 and the sha512 of the same. That's quite secure.

Comment: His secret could be random (it doesn't have to be MD5 or SHA512 of any string). In such case, it's impossible to iterate through all possible secrets (for his length of secret)